# IF THEN formulas combined with ongoing totals formulas

Tags: excel, integer, sum, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet with certain data rules. I need two formulas that go hand-in-hand to track my team's hours. The criterion is: for every 30 hours worked, they earn 1 hour of reward time. Each person has their own column (beginning with C, Row2), and each day of the month is in rows (beginning with ColumnB, 3).

**-1st Formula, Row 35:**
 keep an ongoing calculation/total for each person (cells C35, D35, E35, etc).

**-2nd Formula, Row 37:**
once the total in Row 35 (for each person) hits 30 hours (or increments of 30, ex: 60, 90, etc), Row 37 should reflect how many hours of reward time they've earned. Ex: every 30 hours worked = 1 reward hour earned.

Comment: they were just suggested tags, if you know of any more appropriate ones, suggest away! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want, in C35:

```
=SUM(C3:C34)
```

and in C37:

```
=INT(C35/30)
```

both copied across to suit.